# Convert list values to dictionary rows

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I'm a Python rookie with limited coding experience and this is my first question on this site. I'm really hopeful someone here can help me out.

I am working with some new and some previously existing code. In the previously existing code:

```
members is established as a list array of names
groupID is the ID number for the group
```

For the new code, I need to track the member names in rows with additional information added in the new code. I am attempting to do this with a nested dictionary.

To illustrate this scenario:

```
groupID = 02
members = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo']
memberDetails = {'group': groupID,
                 'currentMembers': {'name': members, 'age': 30, 'sex': 'Male', 'hometown': 'City'}
                      }

print memberDetails
```

I don't care about the values of age, sex and hometown at this point, I'll update those later on and the data will be manipulated further using the keys from the dictionary.

The code above returns:

```
{'group': 2, 'currentMembers': {'hometown': 'City', 'age': 30, 'name': ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo'], 'sex': 'Male'}}
```

I need it to divide into rows, something like:

```
{'group': 2, 'currentMembers': {'hometown': 'City', 'age': 30, 'name': 'John', 'sex': 'Male'}}, {'group': 2, 'currentMembers': {'hometown': 'City', 'age': 30, 'name': 'Paul', 'sex': 'Male'}}, {'group': 2, 'currentMembers': {'hometown': 'City', 'age': 30, 'name': 'George', 'sex': 'Male'}}, {'group': 2, 'currentMembers': {'hometown': 'City', 'age': 30, 'name': 'Ringo', 'sex': 'Male'}}
```

So that I can track hometown and other details based on the name of the member. It would look better in print if it returned in the same order that I enter it in the dictionary, but that is really not important as long as I can store and retrieve the data using the 'name' key.

I have tried to split the list using this line after defining the dictionary:

```
memberDetails['currentMembers'].update({'name': members.split(", ")})
```

However, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I feel like I'm getting close with:

```
for i in members:
    memberDetails['currentMembers']['name'] = i
```

That gets me down to one name but only one row:

```
{'group': 2, 'currentMembers': {'hometown': 'City', 'age': 30, 'name': 'Ringo', 'sex': 'Male'}}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this dictionary or accomplish the goal with another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
groupID = 02
members = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo']
memberDetails = [{
    'group': 2,
    'currentMembers':{
        'name': member,
        'age': 30,
        'sex': 'male',
        'hometown': 'City'
    }
}for member in members]

print memberDetails
```

Comment: Thank you! This does get the list pretty much as requested and the code is simple, which is a plus. However, when I try to reference the information by the dictionary key (e.g., print memberDetails['group']['currentMembers']['name']), I get an error stating "list indices must be integers, not str." So now, I'm wondering what I have to do to reference and/or update the information. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can access in this way..
memberDetails[0].get('currentMembers').get('name')

Comment: memberDetails[0] because it is a list and 'currentMembers' and 'name' is dict key...you can also get ans using memberDetails[0]['currentMembers']['name']

Comment: Thanks Shaon! Really appreciate the help!!

Answer (score 0):

This code here

```
group = {'group': 2}
members = ['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo']
current_members = []
memberDetails = {
    'age': 30,
    'sex': 'male',
    'hometown': 'City'
}
for name in members:
    newMember = memberDetails.copy()
    newMember['name'] = name
    current_members.append(newMember)

group['current_members'] = current_members
print group
```

will output this below. Its a little smaller and less redundant

```
{
    'current_members': [
        {'hometown': 'City', 'age': 30, 'name': 'John', 'sex': 'male'}, 
        {'hometown': 'City', 'age': 30, 'name': 'Paul', 'sex': 'male'}, 
        {'hometown': 'City', 'age': 30, 'name': 'George', 'sex': 'male'}, 
        {'hometown': 'City', 'age': 30, 'name': 'Ringo', 'sex': 'male'}
    ], 
    'group': 2
}
```

The reason why you were getting 1 row, is because the loop was overwriting the previous name with the new name. By copying the memberDetails to a newMember dictionary, you can add a new name, then append it to the current_members list. This way you get each member with their own details